# Mobile tethering [Internal implementation]

Tags: tethering, ipv6

I use mobile tethering sometime from remote. Recently, I had some strange behaviour.

For my older connection when I used to get IPv4 from the operator, on tethering, all the connected devices had a local IP. However, the global IP remained same for the devices.

With my new network operator, I am given IPv6 and here is a twist. All the devices have a different global presence. Does this mean, with tethering on IPv6 connection, LAN concepts are removed?

If yes, how can we create LAN with IPv6 connection?

I no, why am I getting a different global presence inspite of tethering?

I am using OnePlus 3T.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how IPv6 works. Every device gets a unique global address *by design*.